# USB external antenna not working

Tags: networking, wifi, hostapd

I have been experimenting with GPIO control from a local hosted web sever on the raspi 3B+, Unfortunately the range from the built-in antennae is less than adequate for my needs. So I hopped on to amazon and purchased this [https://www.amazon.com/Wifi-Antenna-Raspberry-Pi-Instructions/dp/B00H95C0A2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00H95C0A2) But when I tried to use it doesn't seem to work. It shows in lsusb, but I can't seem to get it to to switch over from using the built-in antennae to the one I bought on amazon. Any help?

Comment: This question is lacking any meaningful data. What OS? What did you try? What does `ls /sys/class/net/` show?

Comment: *built-in antennae to the one I bought on amazon* - you mean built-in **wifi** to this new **adapter**, right, because you've bought a wifi adapter, not just an antenna - so you'll need to follow the "included instructions" - it states right there in the link that instructions are included, perhaps you haven't followed them - it also comes with *Free live tech support* - have you tried them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have purchased isn't only an antenna to replace the built-in antenna (I don't believe that's possible), it is a complete new WiFi transmitter/receiver that can be used in addition to the built-in WiFi. If you do not need the built-in WiFi so just don't configure/use it. You can also completely disable it by adding this option to `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtoverlay=disable-wifi
```

The USB/WiFi dongle is declared to be plug and play. Compatible USB/WiFi adapter are seen out of the box by the operating system so you should also see its interface. Check it with:

```
rpi ~$ ip -br link
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP>
eth0             UP             dc:a6:32:01:db:ec <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
wlan0            DOWN           dc:a6:32:01:db:ed <BROADCAST,MULTICAST>
wlan1            DOWN           00:0e:00:20:08:13 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
```

This is an example from my RasPi with an additional USB/WiFi dongle like yours. Here **wlan0** is the built-in WiFi device and **wlan1** is the additional dongle. I have just plugged it into an USB port. Now you can configure the **wlan1** interface just as you would configure **wlan0**.

Anyway, you should follow the included instructions.